# Blade no reconoce imagenes de plantilla Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo una plantilla principal de la que heredan el resto de blade. En algunos blade no se esta reconociendo la imagen de la plantilla principal. No le encuentro sentido por que algunos blade si lo reconocen y otros no.

Los blade son asi:

```
@extends('plantillas.inicio')
@section('content')
...contenido de esa pagina...
@endsection
```

Todos los blades son asi. La plantilla principal lo que tiene es toda la parte roja que se ve en la siguiente imagen, y los blade que heredan de ella tienen lo que va en el centro, en la parte gris. Algunos no me reconocen el logo de la izquierda. Todas las imagenes que uso estan en una carpeta en la carpeta public.

> Los blade estan en resources/views

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un blade donde no me esta saliendo la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de donde cargo la imagen:

```
<header class="row navbar">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="logo_div">  <img alt="logo" src="imagenes/logo_vicerrectoria_blanco_transparente.png" id="logo_vicerrectoria_navbar"> </div>
         ......
</header>
```

Les muestro las carpetas donde estan los blade y las imagenes:

[image: En esas carpetas estan todos los blade]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muéstranos el código de como cargas esa imagen

Comment: Esto es debido a que tus vistas no se encuentran en el mismo nivel de carpetas que las demás. Puedes mostrar el código de cómo estás cargando la imagen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de public tienes un nivel más al cual acceder que en este caso es `imagenes` dicho lo cual es mejor manejarlo a través del helper `asset` el cual recibe como argumento la ruta relativa y se encargará de completarla.

Queda do así

```
<img alt="logo" src="{{asset('imagenes/logo_vicerrectoria_blanco_transparente.png')}}" id="logo_vicerrectoria_navbar">
```